# queryposts function not working on page 2

Tags: jquery, wordpress, post

When you go to http://birdtowncrossfit.com/wod/ you'll notice daily posts. When you click on previous posts at the bottom, it goes to /pages/2 but the first ten posts still show up. I'd like for ten posts to show up on the first page and the previous ten posts to show up on the next page and so on and so forth.

Comment: can you please post your code for pagination ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$cat = 1;
$showposts = 5; // -1 shows all posts
$do_not_show_stickies = 1; // 0 to show stickies
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array(
    'category__in' => $cat,
    'showposts' => $showposts,
    'caller_get_posts' => $do_not_show_stickies,
    'paged' => $paged
   );
$my_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
<?php query_posts($args); if( have_posts() ) :?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- put title and content tags here -->

<?php endwhile;endif; ?>
```